# Is "martini" plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

Although frequently used incorrectly in English, the borrowed Italian word *paparazzi* should be used for **a group**, while *paparazzo* is **one** intrusive celebrity photographer.

The dictionary defines the plural of *martini* as *martinis*.

But similar to paparazzo, shouldn't *martino* mean **one** such olive-adorned drink, while *martini* mean **several**?

Comment: I do not think there is a rule here as Martinis is the commonly used plural. Martini also has no Italian roots but is "the only American invention as perfect as the sonnet", to quote H. L. Mencken.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martini_%28cocktail%29 Audio: *History of the Martini: A talk with Max Rudin* http://talkinghistory.oah.org/shows/1997/newyear.ra

Comment: We weren't expecting some sort of Italian Inquisition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Who expects the Italian Inquisition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, *martini* is the singular; see here:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/martini

The Italian word is actually derived from the English (not the other way round as your question implies), which probably derives as (same link):

> Origin of MARTINI
>
> probably alteration of Martinez (cocktail), from the name Martinez
> First Known Use: 1894

Comment: Wouldn't Martinus be the singular then ?

Comment: @mgb: Uh? Explain please

Comment: If you think of it as latin. Like the old joke: "A latin teacher goes into a bar and asks for a Martinus. You mean a Martini says the bartender. No I only want one says the teacher".  Or "This bar is so classy I just heard somebody order a Martinus"

Comment: @mgb: If the original comment was a joke, it was only a groaner. (The *old joke* is better.) If the comment was serious, then it's just wrong. Without a happy face I can't tell which is the case. You make a better straight-man than comic I guess.

Comment: As long as you insist on their being 'shaken not stirred' the class of the establishment will not be in doubt.

Comment: 'Bikinus' might raise a few eyebrows. I remember someone asking what the singular of 'confetti' was on one occasion. He didn't appreciate the response 'Parsimonious in the extreme'.

Comment: @Edwin +1: a plaudit for that response.

Comment: Is there a hidden icon somewhere that we can use to "flag as groan inducing"? Granted, I was grinning while groaning. Perhaps we need a grin/groan left right arrow to complement the up/down approval ones.

Comment: Google ngram does not agree with 1894, but maybe there are other uses https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=MARTINI&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMARTINI%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Andrey If you click on the earlier instances, you’ll find they’re all either gibberish or used in Latin titles, as the genitive of the male name _Martinus_ (‘Martin’). The OED does have an earlier use from 1884, though, also mentioned in Sven’s answer below: O.H. Byron’s _Modern Bartenders’ Guide_, “Martinez cocktail… Same as Manhattan, only you substitute gin for whisky.” (Called a “Martini cocktail” in the second quote from 1887.)

Answer (score 6):

Nigel Rees, *Cassell's Dictionary of Word and Phrase Origins* (2002) has this entry for *martini*:

> **martini** There has been a firm, Martini & Rossi, makers of Italian vermouth since 1894, but the origin of the term 'dry martini' may have nothing to do [with] the firm (even though it can, of course, be made with Martini). The 'dry martini' is said to have been invented by Martini di Armi di Taggia, head bartender at the Knickerbocker Hotel, New York City, c.1910. He stipulated one third vermouth, two thirds dry gin. However, Stuart Berg Flexner, in *Listening to America* (1982) finds that people were drinking something called a *martinez* in the US in the 1860s (half gin, half dry vermouth).

Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (2000) has a lively but somewhat different account of the term:

> **martini** H. L. Mencken traced the martini to 1899 and traces the cocktails name from the Martini and Rossi firm, maker of a popular vermouth. Others say the drink originated with a now forgotten Italian or Spanish bartender named Martini. The dry martini is made according to the classic recipe, by drinking a little vermouth, exhaling into the interior of a cocktail glass and filling it with gin—after you drink it you'll forget you forgot the olive. Mencken also mentions the *martini sandwich*, a dry martini between two glasses of beer, which he says, "is favored by many American Linguists."

But the most carefully documented discussion of the origin of the word *martini* as the name of a cocktail appears in Lowell Edmunds, [*Martini, Straight Up: The Classic American Cocktail*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AWfQ2OY1tYoC&pg=PA82&dq=%22Martinez%22+%22martini%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIotmpnbvcxgIVEJeICh0HPwiY#v=onepage&q=%22Martinez%22%20%22martini%22&f=false) (2003)

> O. H. Byron, however, [in *The Modern Bartender's Guide* (1884)] was in fact talking about a "Martinez." That was in 1884. So also in the 1887 edition of Jerry Thomas [*How to Mix Drinks*] it was a "Martinez." "Martini" appears for the first time, so far as I know, in Harry Johnson's manual of 1888 [*New and Improved Illustrated Bartender's Manual, or How to Mix Drinks of the Present Style*]. (There is an earlier edition of 1881 that I have not been able to find.) But in the gruesome plate in this manual illustrating the Martini, it is called a Martine (Figure 6). One would have been tempted to consider this a misspelling if "Martine" did not also show up in Charles Ranhofer's *The Epicureans* (1893). Was there then another name for the drink, pronounced "mar-teen"? In any case "Martine" is never heard of again, and "Martini" and "Martinez" compete for ascendency. "Martinez" appears in Lawlor [*The Mixologist*] (1895), Stuart [*Stuarts Fancy Drinks and how to Mix Them*] (1896), and Paul E. Lowe [*Drinks and How They Are Mixed*] (1904), but already by the time of Lowe, "Martinez" is simply being copied out of earlier books, and one doubts that it was a living name."Martini," the name that, as we know, won out, appears in Wehman [*Bartender's Guide*] (1891), Kappeler [*Modern American Drinks*] (1895), Haywood [*Mixology: The Art of Preparing All Kinds of Drinks*] (1898), anonymous [*Cocktails: How to Make Them*] (1898), Knowles [*The Cocktail Book: A Sideboard Manual for Gentlemen*] (1900), and Daly [*Dalys Bartenders Encyclopedia*] (1903). Since Daly was the barman at the Parker House in Boston, the name "Martini" must have been in use in that city. When one considers that O. Henry mentions "a ready-made Martini" in a story set in the remote village of Mountain Valley, Georgia, in *The Gentle Grafter* of 1904, one concludes that "Martini" was ubiquitous in the United States by the turn of the century.

The mention of "Martini" in Johnson's 1888 bartending manual pretty thoroughly demolishes the claim that Martini & Rossi vermouth is the source of the name, since that company goes back only to 1894, according to Nigel Rees. Still, Rees's emphasis on the term "dry martini" is well considered: according to William Grimes, [*Straight Up or On the Rocks: The Story of the American Cocktail*](https://books.google.com/books?id=P8OjJCf6fLgC&pg=PA62&dq=%22New+and+Improved+Illustrated+Bartender%27s+Manual%22+Johnson&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMIjYnU8MXdxgIVDH6ICh3gFgfp#v=onepage&q=%22martini%22&f=false) (2001), the earliest martines/martinezes/martinis were made with sweet vermouth and tasted nothing like the gin-and-dry-vermouth martinis of today.

In all of the theories of origin of the word *martini* that these various sources discuss—and some theories (such as one involving a gold-rush-era concoction first served in Martinez, California, a town located in the outer reaches of the metropolitan San Francisco Bay Area) seem too far-fetched to take seriously—there appears to be unanimous agreement that the word derived from a proper name (probably either *Martini* or *Martinez*) and so would not support an interpretation of *martini* as a plural loan word from Italian.

---

**Side note:** In the period from 1870 to 1900, "a Martini" was less likely to be understood as a mixed drink than as a rifle, often expressed in compound form as Martini-Enfield or Martini-Henry, depending on which rifle barrel was attached to the Martini breech. The rifle name leads to some rather odd-sounding early occurrences of "Martini" and "Martinis" in the early years, such as this one from Rudyard Kipling, "Fuzzy-Wuzzy (Soudan Expeditionary Force" (1892):

> Our orders was to break you, an' of course we went and did.
>
> We sloshed you with **Martinis**, an it wasn't 'ardly fair;
>
> But for all the odds agin' you, Fuzzy-Wuz you broke the square.

I have not, however, come across any attempt to attribute the cocktail name *martini* to getting "sloshed" with rifle shots.

Comment: Two points, both from the OED: 1) The _Brooklyn Daily Eagle_ on 30 June 1887 had “Sample the bewildering depths of the ‘Martini cocktail’”—a year earlier than the second edition of Johnson’s book, and definitely the current spelling. 2) According to the etymology blurb, Martini and Rossi had an “application for U.S. trade mark incorporating the words _Martini e Rossi_ filed March 16 1882, although earlier use is claimed, and the product is reported to have been exported earlier by the parent company of Martini and Sola”. So the company was perhaps around earlier on after all.

Comment: The origin of the name being related to the California town of Martinez has been proven by historians from E Clampus Vitas, a historical drinking society (or a historical society with a drinking problem) that was well established in the area soon after the initial 1849 gold rush. There was a bar located near the Martinez to San Francisco ferry dock that has been credited with the invention of the drink. We even put up a plaque to commemorate this event. [1992 Plaque photos](http://www.ecv13.org/DisplayPages/martini.html)